# API REST Rules - Should I send the whole entity or just the properties to update

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I am developing a web application with a database.

- In database : I have an entity called Harry with its properties : Id,
  Power, x, y
- For the front-end : I am using Angular.

From Angular, I send to my server the new coordinate of Harry (regarding to its movement), and in the back-end I recover the coordinate with POST.

**My question is :** If I want to adhere to the API REST rules, should the Angular send only the coordinate of Harry or the entire entity, so I can update x and y in the database?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both option could be RESTfull. You have several options:

1) Send POST with entire entity

2) If you always need to update only coordinates, you can use [PATCH](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/).

3) You can also use POST to update only coordinates, if you build new object Id, x,y. But PATCH, probably would be better in this case.

Comment: Can you answer please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430023/using-post-to-recover-the-coordinates-from-front-end

Answer (score 0):

The important thing about Restful APIs is to make sure to use the right HTTP verb.

- `Post` -> Creates a new resource
- `Put` -> Replaces a resource
- `Patch` -> Updates a resource

`Patch` is also more efficient as you only have to send what has changed.
In your case, `patch` is probably preferable.

source: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods

Comment: Can you answer please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430023/using-post-to-recover-the-coordinates-from-front-end