# Using POST to recover the coordinates from front-end

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, api

I am developing a web application with a database.

- In the database : I have an entity called Harry with its properties : Id,
  Power, x, y.
- For the front-end : I am using Angular.

From Angular, I send to my server only the new coordinates of Harry (regarding to its movement), and in the back-end I recover the coordinate with POST.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] int x,[FromBody] y)
   {
     _harryService.VerifyPosition(x,y);
     try
    {
       _harryService.UpdateHarry(id,x,y);
       return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
   {
       return InternalServerError(e);
   }

 }
```

The VerifyPosition Function:

```
 public bool VerifierPosition (int x, int y)
 {
            bool res = false;
            if (carte1[x, y] == 0) res = true;

            return res;
 }
```

The UpdateHarry function:

```
   public void updateHarry(int id,int x,int y)
        {

            var entity = _database.Harries.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id_Harry == id);

            if (entity != null)
            {

                entity.x_harry = x;
                entity.y_harry = y;

                _database.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

**My questions are:**

**1.** Is it a good way to recover the coordonates of Harry with the function Post that I have developed and then call UpdateHarry to update them? Is it RESTful? Or should my Angular send the whole entity for it to be RESTful?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can someone answer please?

Comment: You could implement the PATCH method, instead of using POST, to do partial updates

Comment: @David Can I recover with PATCH what is sent to me by the front end?

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. Try to explain what exactly you try to archive or what problem do you have.